# NSNotificationCenter in a Foundation Tool

Tags: cocoa, networking, foundation

I am creating a server which must run as a privileged helper tool on OS X. In it, I am attempting to use `NSSocketPort`, `NSFileHandle`, and `NSNotificationCenter` to perform asynchronous IO on a listening socket. However, `NSNotificationCenter` refuses to call the notification handler. Here is the relevant code:

```
NSSocketPort* sock = [[NSSocketPort alloc] initWithTCPPort:8080];
NSFileHandle* listener = [[NSFileHandle alloc] initWithFileDescriptor:sock.socket closeOnDealloc:NO]
[NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(onConnection:) name:NSFileHandleConnectionAcceptedNotification object:nil]
```

My main thread is running `[NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop run]`, so that is not the issue. I have tried setting 'object' to 'listener' in the `addObserver:` call, but that made no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Try registering as observer before creating your `NSFileHandle` instance. If the notification is send during the init method, you're registered too late. (I don't have specific experience with `NSFileHandle`, so this is just a hunch for a possible fix.)